# In Gitlab's "config.ru", why "require 'unicorn'" if it's already defined?

Tags: ruby, gitlab, rack, unicorn

I'm doing a deep-dive into how Gitlab's web application works, and I'm starting by looking at the webserver it uses (Unicorn).  The `config.ru` [file](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-foss/blob/master/config.ru) looks like the following:

```
if defined?(Unicorn)
  require 'unicorn'

  if ENV['RAILS_ENV'] == 'production' || ENV['RAILS_ENV'] == 'staging'
    # Unicorn self-process killer
    require 'unicorn/worker_killer'

    min = (ENV['GITLAB_UNICORN_MEMORY_MIN'] || 400 * 1 << 20).to_i
    max = (ENV['GITLAB_UNICORN_MEMORY_MAX'] || 650 * 1 << 20).to_i

    # Max memory size (RSS) per worker
    use Unicorn::WorkerKiller::Oom, min, max
  end
end
```

My question is, if the Unicorn constant is already defined, doesn't that mean the subsequent `require` statement is redundant?  I could see this logic making sense if `if` was changed to `unless`, but otherwise I must be missing something.

I checked the previous commits for this file, and prior to this change, the file looked like the following:

```
# This file is used by Rack-based servers to start the application.

unless defined?(PhusionPassenger)
  # Unicorn self-process killer
  require 'unicorn/worker_killer'

  # Max memory size (RSS) per worker
  use Unicorn::WorkerKiller::Oom, (200 * (1 << 20)), (250 * (1 << 20))
end

require ::File.expand_path('../config/environment',  __FILE__)

map ENV['RAILS_RELATIVE_URL_ROOT'] || "/" do
  run Gitlab::Application
end
```

From the commit which introduced the `if defined?(Unicorn)` and the `require` statement, I understand that the `if` check was introduced as a replacement to `unless defined?(PhusionPassenger)`, because there are many other Rack webservers out there besides Unicorn.  But that doesn't clarify why the subsequent `require` statement was introduced.

Comment: Maybe this commit can explain something? It seems to be just code that should be removed, but it weren't https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-foss/commit/be150fa9913d760802dc4c673ed59930f03ffec0

Comment: @ViniciusBrasil thanks, I updated my question to reflect that commit.  You might be right, that `require` statement could be crufty.  I know that if a library's code has already been `require`'ed previously, an identical `require` statement would return `false`, so I suppose it could easily go unnoticed.

Comment: The project itself could have a file like `unicorn.rb` which would include unicorn specific extensions. The project's lib is first in load path, so `lib/unicorn.rb` would be loaded when `Unicorn` constant is defined. Yeah it doesn't make much sense.